# How do i texture a long cylinder without so much stretch?

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a long cylinder that i am texturing. The texture becomes really stretched because of the long length of the mesh. Is there some way or setting to fix this or is it all about resizing the UV image/tile the texture/finding a higher resolution texture etc.

Edit: Maybe some tricks or tips for the process of texturing theese kinds of things is also much welcome!

Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to paint the texture (texture paint in blender) or do you want to use an image already done ?

Comment: It is just an image texture.

Comment: Thanks for your input but i realise that UV texturing is kind of "art" in it self and i just need to learn and play around/get better with marking seams, managing UV maps and space, layering UV maps etc so that kinda answers my question. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I find that if you're UV-unwrapping the mesh, you need to make sure to apply the scale on the mesh before unwrapping. Do this by selecting the mesh and pressing CTRL+A, then click "Scale" on the popup menu that appears. When that's done, re-unwrap the mesh:

[image]

**Note:** you can also apply the Rotation and Location if needed, and it's generally a good idea to apply Location, Rotation, and Scale on  your mesh before doing things like UV unwrapping, texturing in general, physics effects, particles, etc.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data